# Routing url with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm new to asp.net. I want to create a web sercive using asp.net. I crated a project using [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

I have these class :

```
public class QRCodeItem
{        
    [Key]
    public Byte Version { get; set; }        
    public int PrintPPI { get; set; }
    public int CellSize { get; set; }
}


[Route("api/QRCode")]
[ApiController]
public class QRCodeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/CreateCode/{Version}/{PrintPPI}/{CellSize}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<QRCodeItem>>> CreateCode(Byte Version = 1, int PrintPPI = 300, int CellSize = 5)
    {
        return await _context.QRCodeItems.ToListAsync();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<QRCodeItem>>> GetQRCodeItems()
    {
        return await _context.QRCodeItems.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I try to acces to `CreateCode` with this url :

```
https://localhost:44349/api/CreateCode?Version=1&PrintPPI=300&CellSize=2
```

But I'm unable to call the method. How can I call `CreateCode` using this url ? I can change the method, but not the url.

The url is working with :

```
https://localhost:44349/api/QRCode
```

Method `GetQRCodeItems` is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To use the current code**

`[Route("api/QRCode")]` is the base route for all actions in the controller.

The value in the `Route` attribute of a method is joined on to the base route of the controller.

So for `[Route("CreateCode/{Version}/{PrintPPI}/{CellSize}")]` (note the removal of the leading slash character) the full route is:

`api/QRCode/CreateCode/{Version}/{PrintPPI}/{CellSize}`

`https://localhost:44349/api/QRCode/CreateCode/1/300/2`

**Changing the code to match the URL**

Just drop your route down to:
`[Route("CreateCode")]`

This works because the actual url route ends at `.../CreateCode` without the query string. The parameters after the `?` will be picked up from the query string.

**Extra**

[Microsoft Docs - Combining routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#combining-routes) on how to properly combine routes

> Route templates applied to an action **that begin with a / don't get
>   combined with route templates applied to the controller**. This example
>   matches a set of URL paths similar to the default route

```
[Route("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]      // Combines to define the route template "Home"
    [Route("Index")] // Combines to define the route template "Home/Index"
    [Route("/")]     // Doesn't combine, defines the route template ""
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Home index";
        var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home");
        ViewData["Message"] = "Home index" + "var url = Url.Action; =  " + url;
        return View();
    }

    [Route("About")] // Combines to define the route template "Home/About"
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }   
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. My problem is that I have requirement to use uri with `CreateCode?Version=1&PrintPPI=300&CellSize=2`.

Comment: With `[Route("CreateCode")]` it works perfectly ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The route defined on the method is appended to the route defined at class level so it will be: `https://localhost:44349/api/QRCode/CreateCode?Version=1&PrintPPI=300&CellSize=2`.

Comment: Thank for answer. I've try this, but I have the error `The value 'CreateCode' is not valid.`

Comment: @A.Pissicat have you tried removing the / before CreateCode in joure `Route` attribute? So: `[Route("CreateCode/{Version}/{PrintPPI}/{CellSize}")]`

Comment: Yes, I saw 'a friend' answer but the result is the same.